# Create a long snake

Tags: logical-deduction, mazes

Start from the left bottom corner, you can spin the cell to create a long snake!

Example : 
[image]

Solve this :
[image]

Comment: Does the snake have to end at a side?

Comment: @boboquack : no

Comment: You could have done this with ascii art, so people could rearrange the tiles more easily

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is my snake:

> [image: Snake]

First I had a look at the edges, and did this:

> [image: Step 1]

Then I extended with the chains of Ls:

> [image: Step 2]

Filled in a couple of forced things:

> [image: Step 3]

And the rest was easy (see top)

Comment: That was too quick :-) +1

Comment: Looks more like a worm than a snake -1(*-1)

Comment: The step where you extend the chains of L's pre-supposed that the snake wouldn't leave via an L at the edge.  On the other hand, any place there's a straight line, knowing almost anything about any of its neighbors will reveal whether it must be horizontal or vertical.

Comment: @supercat I know, but it was easier just to assume, and I got an answer anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Here's another version of the snake with both ends on the edges of the grid.

> [image: Snake!]